# Hibernate: Use of primitive long for identifier property

Tags: java, hibernate

According to the Hibernate documentation:

> We recommend that you declare consistently-named identifier properties on persistent classes and that you use a nullable (i.e., non-primitive) type.

Which issue(s) may appear when the GenerationType is set to AUTO and the identifier property is of type long (primitive)?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Long` object i.e. `java.lang.Long`

I think hibernate may have issues with primitive types, because there are occasions when it may try to set it to `null`.

Comment: I know there may have issues with primitive types. My question is what may be these issues.

Comment: There are occasions when it may try to set it to null.

Comment: Do you know what are these occasions?

Comment: I am not sure, at a guess, if you try to insert a new object into the database, that id field would need to be null (for auto increment PK). If its a primitive it will try to insert an item with id of 0 or some default value which wouldnt work.

Comment: I've tried to insert a new instance (with default value for the long identifier i.e. 0) and it works. The property value is changed to the generated identifier.

Comment: hmm, have you tried inserting multiple new instances? When that primitive long id is still 0

Comment: What do you mean by multiple instances? One after the other using the same session? I know that inserting multiple instances using different sessions work, even if the identifier is always 0 at first (i.e. default value for long).

Answer (score 0):

When using Hibernate's 'query-by-example' capabilities a `null` value for the id may be desirable, for example when trying to find a *set* of objects with different id values. In this case, `long id`, defaulting to `0`, may not be the same as `Long id` with a value of `null` - maybe the value `0` is a valid id in the database?

Comment: In my case, the ID 0 is not used in the DB so I don't get this kind of issue.

Comment: Just because `0` is not *used* does not mean that it doesn't make sense from Hibernate's perspective to assume that `0` is actually an id value of an object you are trying to retrieve - which it is not, so that no object will ever be returned in that case. Save yourself the hassle, use `Long` :)